# Why does the MBR return a different offset than Ubuntu's commands?

Tags: command-line, mbr

```
~$ sudo /sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep sda[0-9] 
/dev/sda1   *        2048   234133503   117065728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       234135550   250068991     7966721    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       234135552   250068991     7966720   82  Linux swap / Solaris

~$ cat /sys/block/sda/sda1/start 
2048

~$ sudo hexdump -s 446 -n 64 /dev/sda
00001be 2080 0021 fe83 ffff 0800 0000 9000 0df4
00001ce fe00 ffff fe05 ffff 9ffe 0df4 2002 00f3
00001de 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
00001fe
```

The last command is meant to dump the MBR. You can see from the second to last int (0800 0000) which is little endian, that it encodes 8. 8*512=4098 which is not the 2048 reported by the two other commands. Why is that different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 0800 in hexadecimal form converts to 2048 in decimal form.

The command to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal is:

```
echo "ibase=16; hex-number"|bc
```

Running the command:

```
echo "ibase=16; 0800"|bc
```

Returns the result: `2048`

Comment: haha, wow i feel dumb. i was inverting the nibbles, not just the bytes.